# GRUB2 error - invalid file name "chainloader"

Tags: grub2, uefi, windows-10, bootloader, drive

Used grub customiser to add Windows 10.

Code:

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root D4A8DCD3F31F3A09
chainloader chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Answer (score 4):

`chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` instructs GRUB to chainload (pass control to) Windows Boot Manager which is located at the specified path on the EFI partition. The problem with your code is you put in chainloader twice in succession in the last line of code instead of once. That's why you got an `invalid file name "chainloader"` error message.

Here's an easier way of doing it.

1. In Grub Customizer, select the *List configuration* tab (the first tab) and click the "New entry" icon which looks like a sheet of paper with a green + emblem superimposed on it to add a new entry.
2. Set the following parameters for the new entry:

   - Name: Windows 10
   - Command: chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Comment: Now it says "file EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi can't be found", but it exists on the drive

Comment: `search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root D4A8DCD3F31F3A09` (the 3rd line of your code) searches for the partition with the specified UUID (D4A8DCD3F31F3A09) and sets it as the root partition. This is likely the EFI partition containing Windows boot files. Make sure to select the correct EFI partition in the "Partition" dropdown menu of Grub Customizer.